# React Context value never updates

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have the following code as a component that returns a context. For some reason when I call the `updateUser` function it is not setting the state, I keep getting a blank object. Is there something different I have to do to a function like that when it has parameters?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
const UserContext = React.createContext({
  user: {},
  updateUser: (incomingUser) => {},
});
const UserData = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const updateUser = (incomingUser) => {
    setUser(incomingUser);
    console.log(`user=${JSON.stringify(incomingUser)}`);
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, updateUser }}>
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
export { UserData, UserContext };
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the default value for `UserContext`, or initialise it as null:

```
const UserContext = React.createContext(null);
```

Per the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext):

> When React renders a component that subscribes to this Context object it will read the current context value from the closest matching `Provider` above it in the tree.
>
> The `defaultValue` argument is **only** used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree. This default value can be helpful for testing components in isolation without wrapping them.